# Single Page Application using backbone - templates

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backbone.js

I am creating a single page application (SPA) using backbone. However, I am not sure if I am doing it correct.

Background - I have a main.html file which has, for simplicity, lets say, 3 divs (actually it has 7) in the html body. Now when I am designing my app I find that I need between 2 and 15 divs depending on the functionality provided in a certain route of the app. 
 
What I am curently doing is that I append new divs to the 3 divs inside the templates called by different views.

Question - Is appending new divs against the philosophy of SPA. Because wherever I see explanation of SPAs like [here](http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC690875.png&imgrefurl=https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx&h=609&w=550&tbnid=6EcdarDi2EaciM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=144&usg=__9_l30Jh1Nya0d-BANO4Mj8TcxKg=&docid=PdOMW14xAxbtrM&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ9QEwAGoVChMIn6W2hevqxwIV0n6SCh1OGwG8) I dont see any html template call. All I see is JSON calls.

I'm new to backbone and SPA, so the question may be very naive!

Comment: not pure backbone but good example with marionette - https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction

Comment: It sounds like you might be a bit confused as to what SPA is.  The idea is to load a single page to the client.  The client uses javascript, loaded in this original page and/or dynamically, to update the view based on user actions or other events, which may trigger additional requests for data from the server using Ajax. The server typically returns this data in the form of JSON you see in the diagram you referenced.  This is a highly simplified description, but I hope it'll steer you in the right direction, but 'appending divs' is not in itself "bad". It's just one way to update the view.

Comment: @caasjj - thanks for the explanation, you said appending divs is one way of doing it. What are some other ways of accomplishing the same task?

Comment: What you're really doing is modifying what is rendered on the screen, either by modifying the DOM itself (adding or removing any element, such as DIV, UL, IMG, etc.) or changing the render tree (e.g. changing CSS visibility, etc.)  These will all alter the state of the SPA.  You really should take the time to read something like http://www.amazon.com/Single-Page-Applications-end-end/dp/1617290750?tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-20

Comment: @caasjj - thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it!